# Does Google Analytics Require Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

Do I need to include a jQuery library for Google Analytics to run? Or does it run off JavaScript?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It'd be a bit crap if it did.

Comment: It took me 30 seconds, look [HERE](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's completely standalone and yes it's (pure) Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

GA runs independent of jQuery.